# Pass Type from parent component to a child user control in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, csvhelper

I'm creating a user control to import csv file 'using CsvHelper;',

**Parent Component**

```
<ImportCsv Id="importCsv" sizeAllowedInKB=@fileSize typeAllowed=@fileTypeAllowed csvRows=@csvRowsType name="Import csv" />

@code{
        private Type csvRowsType = typeof(CsvRows); 
        // CsvRows will always be different as this component can be user across project
}
```

**Child component**

```
<InputFile id="@Id" OnChange="@LoadFiles" accept="@typeAllowed" class="button button-small" />
<span title="add" class="icon-plus"></span>@name

@code{
        [Parameter] public string typeAllowed { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public int sizeAllowedInKB { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public Type csvRows { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string name { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

        private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"StreamReader {reader.ReadToEnd()}");
                        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        var csvReords = csv.GetRecords(Type.GetType(csvRows.FullName));
                        Console.WriteLine($"type of csvRows {csvRows} record count {csvReords.Count()} fullName {Type.GetType(csvRows.FullName)} ddd {csvRows.GetType()}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Serialize {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(csvReords)}");
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: {Filename} Error: {Error}", e.File.Name, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Issue hear is I can see csv data on console

```
Console.WriteLine($"StreamReader {reader.ReadToEnd()}");
```

I can see type I'm passing from Parent

```
Console.WriteLine($"type of csvRows {csvRows} record count {csvReords.Count()} fullName {Type.GetType(csvRows.FullName)} ddd {csvRows.GetType()}");
```

but somehow

```
var csvReords = csv.GetRecords(Type.GetType(csvRows.FullName));
```

not returning anything, count is zero

Comment: When you did `Console.WriteLine($"StreamReader {reader.ReadToEnd()}");` you **read all the way to the end of the stream**.  So CsvReader won't find anything left to read.  Removing the `reader.ReadToEnd()` should resolve that particular problem.

Comment: my initial code has without console only, added particular console just to check if I'm getting csv content, even if I remove 'reader.ReadToEnd()' still record count is zero

Comment: If removing `reader.ReadToEnd()` doesn't resolve the problem, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a CSV file and type that demonstrate the problem?  See [ask].  Thanks!

Comment: According to [`the docs`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file), *The `GetRecords<T>` method will return an `IEnumerable<T>` that will yield records.*  What that means is that, when you do `csvReords.Count()`, it reads through the file to get the number of records.  Then you do `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(csvReords)` once again the reader has already read to the end and so can't be reused.  If you need to load it into memory for repeated access, use `csv.GetRecords(Type.GetType(csvRows.FullName)).ToList()` to load it all into memory at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue, commenting solution in case someone still looking for the same

**Parent**

```
<ImportCsv TValue=CsvRows Id="importCsv" sizeAllowedInKB=5 typeAllowed=".csv" name="Import Csv" csvData="ConsumeData" />

@Code
{
   private void ConsumeData(List<CsvRows> csvData)
   {
      // Consume csv Data
   }
}
```

**Child**

```
public partial class ImportCsv<TValue> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] public int sizeAllowedInKB { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string typeAllowed { get; set; } = ".csv";
        [Parameter] public string name { get; set; } = "Import csv";
        [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; } = "ImportCsv";
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<TValue>> csvData { get; set; }

        private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                       CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                       var csvReords = csv.GetRecords<TValue>().ToList();
                       csvData.InvokeAsync(csvReords);
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: {Filename} Error: {Error}", e.File.Name, ex.Message);
            }
     }
```

Comment: You should try to explain why this solution works, or tell people that you don't know why it works